# Asp.net mvc views for many to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Good day guys, I created few models that implement a many to many relationship; now I'm having problems correctly formatting/designing the 'Create and Edit' views.
Here are my models:

**Student Model**

```
namespace HMS.Models
{
    [Table("Students", Schema ="Admission")]
    public class Students : Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int StudentId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }               

        // this associate a student with a list of guardian  
        public virtual ICollection<Guardian> Guardians { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Guardian Model**

```
namespace HMS.Models
{
    [Table("Guardians", Schema ="Admission")]
    public class Students : Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int GuardianId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }               

        // this associate a student with a list of guardian  
        public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**StudentGuardian Model**

```
namespace HMS.Models
{
    [Table("StudentGuardian", Schema ="Admission")]
    public class Students : Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Guardian Id")]
        [ForeignKey("GuardianId")]
        public int GuardianId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Student Id")]
        [ForeignKey("StudentId")]
        public string StudentId { get; set; }               
    }
}
```

A student can have multiple guardians and a guardian multiple students. How do I format the 'Create' view to enter these related objects?

Comment: If I got what you want, I guess you should have 2 views. One of them from the perspective of the student where the user will choose the guardians to associate with him. And a second one where, in an analogous way, will allow the user to select the students he wants to associate with a specific guardian.

Comment: @Luty that is exactly what I want to do but don't know how to implement it.

Comment: your model names are wrong.may be a typo.

Comment: @Sampath the problem is not with my models names. The problem I faced is in creating a view in which a guardian can select multiple person and a person can do likewise. By far the only link that I found to be a little helpful is this: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application but the logic implemented here is very difficult to withhold. I really need you guys help in doing this please.

Answer (score 0):

You can design UI as shown below.

**Note :**  Here Guardians is a drop down where can be selected more than one Guardian by multiselecting.You have to use multiselecting dropdown for that.

[image]

You can read more about this here :  [**Many to Many Relationship : a step by step View Model approach**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/702890/MVC-Entity-Framework-and-Many-to-Many-Relation)