# Accessing the properties of a many-to-many join entity's navigation properties

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a many-to-many relationship between `Post` and `Tag`, represented by the join entity `PostTag`. I am currently able to access the `PostTag` table in my `Details` view of the `Post` class; for example, I can view a particular `Post` and display the associated `PostTags`. However, I have only been able to display the `PostTag` properties `PostId` and `TagId`, while I'd like to display properties related to the `Tag` class via the `PostTag` entity.

There are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40663363/asp-net-mvc-views-for-many-to-many-relationship) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531769/saving-many-to-many-relationship-data-on-mvc-create-view) online detailing ways to display many-to-many relationships, but they all seem to be broadly different to the approach I have taken, and so do not seem to be easily translatable to my project.

**Models**

```
public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } // primary key
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }

        public ICollection<PostTag> PostTags { get; } = new List<PostTag>();
    }

public class Tag
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public ICollection<PostTag> PostTags { get; } = new List<PostTag>();
    }

public class PostTag
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public Post post { get; set; }

        public int TagId { get; set; }
        public Tag tag { get; set; }
    }
```

**Relevant part of PostsController**

```
public class PostsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly Website.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public PostsController(Website.Data.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        // GET: Post/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details([Bind(Prefix = "Id")]int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var post = await _context.Post
                .Include(p => p.Author)
                .Include(p => p.PostTags)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (post == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

           return View(post);
        }
    }
```

**Db context**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Author> Author { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Post { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Tag> Tag { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PostTag> PostTag { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            builder.Entity<PostTag>()
                .HasKey(t => new { t.PostId, t.TagId });
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
@model Website.Models.Post
@foreach (var postTag in Model.PostTags)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => postTag)
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

This view displays the `PostTags` associated with a particular `Post`. For example, at `https://localhost:xxxxx/Posts/Details/1`, the `Post` with `Id == 1` is accessed, and its associated `Tags` are displayed.

```
PostId
1
TagId
2
PostId
1
TagId
4
PostId
1
TagId
5
```

I can't seem to access `Tag.Title`; for example, `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => postTag.tag.Title)` does not display any view. My desired output would be, assuming `Tag` rows of `Fiction`, `Nonfiction` and `Classic` have `Id` values equal to `2`, `4` and `5`,

```
Fiction
Nonfiction
Classic
```

Appreciate any advice here.

**edit:**
Upon loading the Details page in debug mode, the `post` variable contains all the expected properties including `PostTags`. `PostTags` contains the expected number of elements (three `PostTag` elements because this `Post` instance has three associated `Tags`). Each element contains properties of `PostId`, `TagId`, `post` and `tag`; however, `tag` is `null`. This is the issue, as I'm trying to access `tag.Title`. Screenshot of local variables below:

[image: local variables]

Comment: try .Include(p => PostTags.Tag). Also please check if your lazy loading is enabled on your context. it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I don't seem able to access any other properties from `PostTags` in that `Include()` call. I'm not sure what lazy loading is, will have a look at that. I'll edit my post to include my context now.

Comment: @heds1 If you are unfamilar with `LINQ` syntax, try using `LINQ Query` syntax. In that way you can define your `joins` as required. Tutorial can be found here: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-query-syntax

Comment: @RahulSharma Hi, thanks for the comment. My understanding is that the controller is using LINQ to access the `PostTags` (`var post = await _context.Post.Include(p => p.PostTags).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);`). My issue is that I'm not sure how to access the navigation property `Tag`, and its property `Title`.

Comment: @heds1 Are you able to get your required data in your `Post` model specifically in your IColletction `PostTags`. Have you tried to debug and see if your query is returning you the data that is needed?

Comment: @RahulSharma Good question; upon loading the Details page, the `post` variable does contain a `PostTags` property, which contains three elements (for the three `PostTags` associated with that `Post`). However, each `PostTag` element contains `PostId`, `TagId` and `post` properties, but the `tag` property is `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could include multiple levels of related data using the [ThenInclude](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data?view=aspnetcore-2.1) method.

```
var post= await _context.Post
                        .Include(p => p.Author)
                        .Include(p => p.PostTags)
                        .ThenInclude(pt => pt.Tag)
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
```

many-to-many DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
        .HasKey(pt => new { pt.PostId, pt.TagId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
        .HasOne(pt => pt.Post)
        .WithMany(p => p.PostTags)
        .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.PostId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
        .HasOne(pt => pt.Tag)
        .WithMany(t => t.PostTags)
        .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TagId);
}
```

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?view=aspnetcore-2.1#other-relationship-patterns

Comment: Brilliant, applying the `ModelBuilder` correctly is what I was missing. Thanks a lot.